# NestJS StreamableFile is changing bytes when streaming a pdf

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, swagger, nestjs

I'm trying to download a pdf file from an s3 bucket, however for security reasons the file must be streamed back to the client (an angular web app). My plan was to request a download link from s3 and stream the document from that link back to the client using NestJS StreamableFile.

My Controller:

```
@Post('download')
    @ApiOkResponse({
      schema: {
        type: 'string',
        format: 'binary'
      }
    })
    @ApiProduces('application/pdf')
    async documentDownload(@Body() body: DownloadURLRequest) {
      const result = await this.service.getS3DownloadURL(body);
      const got = require('got');
      return new StreamableFile(got.stream(result.downloadUrl));
    }
```

My client receives a Blob that is exactly the length of the original file, however the file fails to load. Upon closer inspection it turns out some of (roughly 2/3) the bytes are different.

After a bit of debugging I know for sure the got.stream is generating the correct bytes, so it would appear that StreamableFile is changing or misinterpreting some of the bytes for some reason. Anyone with experience using StreamableFile know why this might be? Or if there is a better way to handle this with NestJS or otherwise I'm open to suggestions.

Edit: Further testing -- printing the stream from the StreamableFile object on the API side shows correct bytes, however the file returned to swagger has incorrect bytes.

Comment: Does it produce the right number if you set the content-type header?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel using swaggers decorators for the header, setting it again to application/pdf yes it produces the same result. Correct number of bytes but they're different

Comment: The swagger decorators don't modify the actual server response, they just set the value s for swagger's knowledge. What does `return new StreamableFile(got.stream(result.downloadUrl), { type: 'application/pdf' })` do? Does it send the PDF correctly?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel It produces exactly the same file as before, roughly 2/3 different from the original and cannot be opened

Comment: So the return from the server directly (i.e. not using swagger) is also ~2/3 the size, or is it only ~2/3 on the swagger? Trying to find the place where the bytes get messed up.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel To be clear, the file size at all points is correct. The issue is the bytes are not matching up. On the API side the bytes are correct. However the output both on the client and in swagger are not. Looking deeper into this it seems to be an encoding issue. For example µ is being interpreted as ½ï

Comment: Hmm, [as you can see the streamable file just takes in the stream](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/file-stream/streamable-file.ts#L27-L39) and eventually gets called with [`stream.pipe(res)`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.ts#L85-L95). I wonder if this is something express is messing with or an issue with how the client is decoding it

Comment: @JayMcDoniel so it looks like B5 in the buffer on the original document is µ however in the streamed document it is replaced with EF BF BD or  ï¿½ which seems to be filler for unrecognized bytes. This seems like an encoding issue however both documents claim to be encoded in ANSI so I'm not sure why it's being streamed improperly